# Podcasts: Where can I find the average duration of episodes in a series?

Tags: data-request, media

It is easy to export an opml file from a podcast app. That provides me with information such as this.

```
<outline text="This Week in Google (MP3)" type="rss" xmlUrl="http://feeds.twit.tv/twig.xml"  htmlUrl="https://twit.tv/shows/this-week-in-google" />
```

Is there a database or a method by which I could pull (or lookup or calculate) the average (or median) duration of each episode?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the XML for that podcast you'll see that it is structured like this

```
channel
  stream description
  item
    item description
  item
    item description
  …
```

where the items are the individual episodes and the item description includes a whole lot of tags containing metadata about each episode. One of the metadata is the description tag which looks like

```
<itunes:duration>2:03:55</itunes:duration>
```

So all you need to do is parse the XML (using whatever XML parsing framework works for you, for example [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) in python would do it like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('thefile.xml').getroot()
```

Then loop through the items and get their itunes:duration. I'm a bit rubbish with ElementTree, but this worked for me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# I downloaded the xml from my browser, but you could grab it here instead
root = ET.parse('twig.xml').getroot() 
channel = root.getchildren()[0]
d = list(channel.iter('{http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd}duration'))
for i in d:
  print i.text
  #doSomeParsingOfTheTimeStringsHere(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

No. An OPML file only describes the feeds, not the individual posts in the feeds, let alone the (usually) MP3 files referenced *from* each post. And then again, those references are only links without size/duration information.

Comment: Thank you. But yes, armed with a list of feeds, where can one go to lookup the median episode duration?

Comment: Read the second half of my answer again. You can't, usually not until you have actually downloaded the podcasts.